# scrollto activating on first click

Tags: javascript, onclick, scrollto

I have a scrollto function that works by clicking a background div that wraps the content.

In the content theres a number of thumbnail links that shouldn't activate the scrollto function when clicked. I have a stop propogation event in place but it still seems to be affecting the *very first click made*.

[Here's a demo of what i mean](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AFCql). The links/red blocks are target blank but you'll notice after clicking them and returning to the codepen that the viewfinder has scrolled down to the row below. However clicking the wrapper/background first and then a link, the problem doesn't occur.

Can anyone shine any light on this first click issue?!

Comment: Please include your code or create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

This is just because you set your click event on $('a') inside the click event on $('#wrapper')... So you're telling to listen for $('a').click(); after having clicked on $('.#wrapper') first.

Just move this part outside of the `wrapper click listener` :

```
  //Stop links affecting scroll function
  $("a").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```